# Tricolorations of a flag

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose that the there are 6 colors of the rainbow - red, orange, yellow, green, blue, and purple, in that order. (indigo is not included) Chan wants to design a vertical tricolor (a flag with equal vertical stripes of three different color) for a club. If Chan uses only uses the 6 rainbow colors and that the three colors appear in red-to-purple rainbow order from left to right, then how many different tricolors are possible?

example that works:

[image]

I know that the first section of the flag has 4 choices: red, orange, yellow, and green, because the 2 sections after it need to come after the color in rainbow order. So, the second section has 4-1 = 3 choices, and the third section has 3-1= 2 choices. But, I'm not sure if I am finding the right number of choices for sections 1 and 2 of the flag.

Comment: Just choose three colors.  Only one ordering is allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we want three different colors, choosing which three of the six colors are used completely determines the flag since they must be arranged in red-to-purple rainbow order.  For instance, choosing red, yellow, and green means the tricolor will be red, yellow, green, in that order.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{6}{3}$$
possible tricolor flags.